# Assigning Object at Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to Achieve Something like this

```
var mainList = Model.ContentItems;
Dictionary<string, string> dictTerms = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var outeritems in mainList) {
    string page = ".Page";
    dynamic Terms = outeritems.ContentItem + page;
}
```

I am doing this because the object is coming from database and i don't know the object field.
So I will first loop through all the objects and then will do something like this to get the actual value of the field. I know it will convert it to string but is there anything I dont know yet where I can do this.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to get the properties of a Class, then use Reflection concepts. Reference - http://abundantcode.com/how-to-get-the-property-value-using-reflection-in-c/

Comment: Be advised that reflection is still *very* slow, and should be used sparingly if at all, but @ramiramilu is right: if you *really* need to do something like this, reflection is the way to go.

Comment: Thanx @ramiramilu that's exactly what I was looking for as I have heard about reflection but I never knew where and how to use it. Thanx.

Comment: @AliasgarRajpiplawala If my comments helped you, can I post it an answer?

Comment: Yes you can what you have mentioned is right but there is another problem I am facing in this by using reflection so i will post that question in separate thread but your suggestion was correct.